# Dockerized Flask: Connection reset by peer

Tags: docker, python

Trying to connect to a dockerized Flask app fails with error 104, 'Connection reset by peer' using this minimal example:

app.py:

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def hello():
    return "Hello World!"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:alpine
RUN pip install flask
COPY . /src/
EXPOSE 5000
ENTRYPOINT ["python", "/src/app.py"]
```

docker-compose.yml:

```
…
test:
    build: .
    ports:
        - 127.0.0.1:5000:5000
```

Flask app seems to be running as expected:

```
$ docker logs test 
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
```

Trying to connect from outside fails:

```
$ http http://127.0.0.1:5000/
http: error: ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(104, 'Connection reset by peer')) while doing GET request to URL: http://127.0.0.1:5000/
```

Any ideas, why I can't get to see "Hello World!" here?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

> Trying to connect from outside fails

Are you actually connecting from *outside*? Flask is binding to localhost (127.0.0.1) and that will only be reachable from within the container. If you're on your local machine, you'll need flask to bind to all IP's:

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello():
    return "Hello World!"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0')
```

That works for me successfully.

Comment: Thats right. Never thought this is actually a python or flask problem, as I just copied it from [the docs](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Flask). Thx

Comment: Or with gunicorn: `gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:5000 app:app`

Comment: If you're using `flask run`, use `--host=0.0.0.0`. Or in the Dockerfile: `CMD ["flask", "run", "--host=0.0.0.0"]`

Comment: I have been looking for this for 4 days >D lol

Comment: +1 You saved my day :)  So happy to find this answer after 20 min and not 4 days